# Cocoa Bindings and Core Data with multiple entites

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm working on a simple app that could use Core Data and Cocoa Bindings.

I have created 2 entites: Film and Klient with many-to-many relationship.
Then I created TableView with one column just to show Film name. Just next to that TableView I created some TextFields to allow user to write some things into Klient entity (name, city etc). I also made 2 Array Controllers one for Film one for Klient.  I binded Film Array Controller with TableView and Klient Array Controller with TextFields.

I want to create something like this.

When I select film from TableView I want to see who "bought" that film - so I want when film is selected to change values in TextFields.

Is this possible with ArrayControllers and Cocoa Bindings? I don't want to write any code..

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You seed to setup both content and selection bindings between the AC and tableView, and you can then bind the klient AC's content to the film AC's selection.klients (or whatever) though I think you need to clarify which klient of the many is being displayed.

Comment: But there is no content bindings in TextField..

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention text field bindings because they're fairly straightforward and documented in the Cocoa Bindings Reference, as well as discoverable in Interface Builder.  You bind their value to an AC's selection with an additional keypath for the entity attributes for this sort of thing.